# Is there any way to get data from array in firestore in android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the data from `user_stories` like story and `story_start` and `story end`?

Here is the image of my Firestore database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your database schema, your `user_stories` property is of type array. This means, that when you try to get that document, you get that propery as a `List` of objects and **not** as an array. Unfortunately, Firestore cannot convert that list to a list of custom objects, you have to do it yourself. So please try this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference sendStoriesRef = rootRef.collection("sendstories");
sendStoriesRef.document("kueIJcdQARzEKU7EVio9").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                List<Map<String, Object>> list = (List<Map<String, Object>>) document.get("user_stories");

                //Iterate through the list to get the desired values
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Now simply iterate through the list to get the desired values. If `kueIJcdQARzEKU7EVio9` is the `uid` of the user, than simply change that value with this `uid`:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```